# Fill IE form with VBA if only ng-model is known

Tags: angularjs, excel, vba, internet-explorer, angular-ngmodel

Webpage:

```
input ng-model="vm.form.model.maxDepth" type="text" 
class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" style=""
```

Type and Class are same at all fields. So I can only use Ng-model. How to fill the IE form?

Non of this worked:

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate ("https://page.com")
Set daug = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2")
i = 1
oIE.document.all.Item("vm.form.model.maxDepth")(1).Focus
oIE.document.all("vm.form.model.maxDepth")(1).innerText = daug(i)
oIE.document.all("vm.form.model.maxDepth")(1).Value = daug(i)
oIE.document.all("vm.form.model.maxDepth")(1).innerText = daug(i)
oIE.document.parentWindow.execScript.angular.element(document.getElementByTagName("input")(15)).scope().vm.form.Model.maxDepth = "112233"
oIE.document.qetElementsByClassName("vm.form.model.maxDepth").Value = daug(i)
oIE.document.parentWindow.execScript.angular.element(document.getElementByTagName("input")(15)).scope().vm.form.Model.maxDepth = "112233"

For Each element In oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If InStr(element.vbTextCompare, "vm.form.model.maxDepth") <> 0 Then

If element.hasAttribute("ng-model") & element.getAttribute("ng-model") = "vm.form.model.maxDepth" Then
Debug.Print (element.innerText)
    element.Value = daug(i)
    Exit For
End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm working on the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376570/how-to-manipulate-a-class-in-a-html-to-select-a-value-in-a-dropdownbox-from-vba?noredirect=1#comment79735990_46376570) If you could share the more complete html of the dropdownbox you are trying to change, we can share a more general solution if either of us solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
Set oIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

Comment: Please comments section if its query regarding a question